# Typescript is not finding scope or attributes inside of my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript

I am using typescript really more for error checking and typing for my application and not really using any of the ES6 style code but I am running into a problem. In my angular directive **scope.animate** and **attr.animate** in my link function are not being recognized by typescript I installed the typings for angular and jquery and I have the reference links in place.  Is there something I am missing? this is my Typescript file (main.ts).

```js
/// <reference path="typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="typings/angularjs/angular-animate.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="typings/greensock/greensock.d.ts"/>
var app = angular.module("App", ["ngAnimate"]);

app.factory("DataService", ()=>{
 
 var data = {};
 
 return data;
 
});

app.service("Notify", function(){
 
 var notifyService = this;
 
 notifyService.message = "Some message."; 
 notifyService.test = function(){
  return "new Message";
 }
 
 notifyService.showHide = false;
 
 notifyService.setShowHide = function(value:boolean){
  
  notifyService.showHide = value;
  
 }
 
 notifyService.setMessage = function(val){
  
  notifyService.message = val;
  
 }
 
 notifyService.style = "color:white; font-weight:bold; background-color:black;"
 
})

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope, $q, $http, Notify, DataService) {
 
 var appCtrl = this;
 appCtrl.notify = Notify;

});

app.animation(".fade", function(){
 
 return {
  addClass:function(element, className){
   if(!TweenMax.isTweening(element))
    TweenMax.to(element, 2, {opacity:1})
  },
  removeClass:function(element, className){
   if(!TweenMax.isTweening(element))
    TweenMax.to(element, 2, {opacity:0})
  }
 }
 
});

app.directive("clickable", function (Notify, DataService, $http):ng.IDirective{
 
 return {
  restrict:"ACE",
  scope:{
   animate:"@"
  },
  link:function(scope, element, attr){
        
            scope.animate;
   
   element.bind("click", function(){

    scope.$apply(function(){
     
     Notify.setMessage("Message from click event");
     console.log(Notify.message);
  
     
    })
    
   });
   
  }
 }
 
})

angular.element(document).ready(function(){
 
 angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector("body"), ["App"]);
 
})
```

Comment: Is this your compiled js file or this is the ts file? if it is ts file, then element and attr without any type specification should just be of type `any` so you should not get any of these issues.

Comment: this is my typescript file.  It won't compile when I try to use the scope.animate or access the attr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really weird that without any typings you get this error. Generally you can expect this error if you were to do:

```
    link:function(scope:ng.IScope, 
               element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery,
               attrs: ng.IAttributes,){
```

But you aren't so by default those arguments should be of type `any`. However you should be able to fix it by creating custom types:

```
interface clickableVM extends ng.IScope{
    animate:string;
}

interface clickableAttrs extends ng.IAttributes{
    animate:string;
}
```

and set them to the arguments:

```
 link:function(scope:clickableVM , 
               element: any,
               attrs: clickableAttrs){
```

Comment: That fixed it. I guess you had to add it to the IScope Interface that is in the Angular typing.  I am still a little new to typescript.  I have written C# code before and done asp.net MVC so typescript was a bit easier to pickup. but I am just surprised it didn't recognize the scope object.  It was recognizing it.

Comment: Would I have to do the same thing for the Controllers as well?

Comment: @Jesse it depends. You necessarily do not have to do that. But that is the whole purpose of using `Type`script. :)

Comment: OK I will do some more experimentation with it.